# TikTok API oauth

Tags: api, authentication, oauth, tiktok

I'm trying to implement TikTok login kit into my app.
I'm following this guide https://developers.tiktok.com/doc/login-kit-web and i'm stuck on point 2.1 because after succesfully login the user, and succesfully grant app permissions from the user i'm beeing redirect to this url : `https://open-api.tiktok.com/platform/oauth/undefined`

I'm pretty sure my url is correct because if i insert in it some errors on purpose i get an error page .. like wrong client key, wrong response type, scope, redirect url ecc..

Anyone knows what am i doing wrong?

thanks!

Comment: I had this error when I had no "callback URL" set for my app. You need to > login to tiktok developer portal > My Apps (select your app) > Scroll down to "Platform info". The callback URL needs to be a server endpoint you control, as you will recieve data from tiktok once a user has completed (or failed) the login to that url.

Answer (score 1):

Ok i figured it out.

it was my fault because i created a tiktok-app for applications but by using oauth in browser you nedd to create a web based tiktok-app.

Comment: Not in my case. I have the same problem and my app was created for web. Do you have any other idea on what caused it? Did you create a completely new app maybe set up something in another way?

Comment: My app is under review. Do I need to wait until the review is completed because my web config platform didn't set in the first place, before the review